# some keys behave strange on login screen

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, login-screen

I use XUbuntu. I updated recently. I have 105generic keyboard.

When I try to log in, some keys don't work as expected:

```
7,8,9,u,i,o,.,- give nonsense like ^[[1~
0 turns out to /
P gives *
```

These are all keys which can be typed together with <kbd>fn</kbd> to give another character.

---

- Why is this happening?
- How to make them work back normal?

---

EDIT:
I tried to reset keyboard settings, by:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
sudo service keyboard-setup restart
```

Now, the keyboard behaves strange EVERYWHERE.
I work around this using an external keyboard, but this is annoying since I work on a notebook.

---

## tl,dr

- when I press a key with a fn extra output, I get that one, or nonsense or nothing (nonsense in terminal, nothing everywhere else)
- to use real functions, e.g. changing audio volume with keys only, I have to press fn -> Fn-key is not broken, it's the software

---

EDIT2: anything was back in first state, after

- unchecking in keyboard-settings the box "use system-wide settings"
- and rebooting

So I am back were I cannot login, but can use for working the notebook keyboard.

Another symptom: I don't get any special characters using fn (the key), but I'm not sure whether I could do this before, but I think yes.

please note: I am quite sure I used the keyboard layout `intel generic 105` ever since.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know *why* this worked.

But I do know it worked.

---

Since only keys that react to fn key changed behavior, I thought fn was locked. (It wasn't)

So I turned on and off num lock (using fn+f11).

Surprisingly, the login screen worked back normal.